# Ubuntu server time jumping away

Tags: ubuntu, ntpd, date

I wanted to write "drifting away" in the header but this is not what's happening. I have an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server running some web apps. On 25.10.2014 I updated tzdata to the latest version and yesterday - 30.10.2014 - strange things began to happen. At approximately 4:30 AM server time jumped a week back - to 24.10.2014 4:42 AM. Today - 31.10.2014 - the same thing happened again. At 3:32 AM server time jumped ~24h back - to 30.10.2014 4:22 AM.

Both times I found ntpd daemon turned off. Server uptime is 10+ days. Any ideas on what might be happening or how I can trace it?

Comment: Is this a virtual server or dedicated hardware?

Comment: It is virtual server, but as I found out hypervisor's time is intact.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like purging `ntp` and installing it back again solved the case. The time hasn't jumped any more. Still don't know what was the reason of it.